# how to share build artifact between codebuild inthe same codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, artifact

I am using codepipeline for a python project build. For project reason, I have to seperate the packaging and upload to two stages.
In the packaging stage, I used the poetry to build the wheel file, and saved to artifact as

```
artifacts:
  base-directory: ./dist/
  files:
    - "**/*"
```

I can find the files are saved to S3,

My question is:
in the follow stage, how I can refer to the wheel files generated by this codebuild  without re-packing it?